# Hey evreone! (Python)

Tags: python

I have a program that creates a file and writes many lines to it.

```
def save():
    f = open("newfile.txt", "w")
    f.write("""\
    Hey!     
    How are u?
    Good Bye!
    """)
save()
```

And I need it to write lines at the beginning, not with 4 spaces. Also, so that it is like the first option and not like this:

```
def save():
    f = opne("newfile.txt", "w")
    f.write("""\
Hey!     
How are u?
Good Bye!
    """)
save()
```

Comment: Your code does not work (`opne` ?). Look into `with open(...)` and `str.strip()`.

Comment: The point of a title is to indicate the content of the question.

Comment: Jan, Ohh sorry. Im bad writed code in site. I now change)

Comment: khelwood Sorry, Im just dont use the site often

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```py
def save():
    f = open("newfile.txt", "w")
    f.write(
        "Hey!\n"
        + "How are u?\n"
        + "Good Bye!\n"
    )
    f.close()

save()
```

Comment: AAAlex123, Thank you!